# docker run command ends up in : nginx: [emerg] unknown directive “events” in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, config, server-sent-events

I have installed nginx-extras from Ubuntu bash shell in my desktop Windows 10 O.S. The is required to spin up a docker container for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor web assembly application for serving the static web pages. My nginx.conf:

```
 events { }
   http {
      include mime.types;
      types {
         application/wasm wasm;
       }
     server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html;
        location / {
           root /var/www/web;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
     }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/web
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

My build command was successful.

However when I wanted to create a container using the command: docker run -p 8080:80 docker-wasm-blazor It gave me an error:

[emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "events" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "events" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

**I am very new to nginx and containerisation**,  so any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: if I build an image from `nginx:alpine` using your `nginx.conf`, it all seems to work just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate through an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor Web Assembly as I am doing? Even so, as I wrote above, I am able to create an image with the build command. However when I issue the docker run command (to create an image instance or container) that it's ending up with the error.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. Fixed by changing the encoding of the nginx.conf file. If you create the nginx.conf file in/with visual studio (Add -> new File) it's most likely that your will get the wrong encoding (other people got the same error).

In my case the encoding was UTF-8 and I needed us-ascii encoding. The easiest was to delete my nginx.conf file and recreate it outside of visual studio (I used Sublime text but I think you can use notepad).

Comment: Oh Man, you hit the nail right on the head. I created the conf file using Add -> New Item Class.cs. Then renaming it and editing it. Now I deleted that, then got that from a [git hub source](https://github.com/jongio/BlazorDocker/tree/master/Standalone).

Comment: Omg thank you! That's so bad to get config encoding error in 2022... In my case I converted UTF-16 to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the issue by excluding the custom nginx.conf file to copy over the default nginx.conf file by removing the last line from the dockerfile. Now my dockerfile looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM nginx
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot/ .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and fixed it by removing the white spaces from before and after "events" and "http", so my config file become:

```
events{}
http{
    include mime.types;
types {
    application/wasm wasm;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # Here, we set the location for Nginx to serve the files
    # by looking for index.html
    location / {
        root /usr/local/webapp/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
}
```